# Enable/Disable Interface Builder uibutton programmatically

Tags: iphone, button

In my mapkit app,  I would be able  to enable/disable programmatically buttons created via Interface Builder.  The idea is enable a one or more button if a annotatios is selected, and disable if not.  for example, in my, an action:

```
-(void)traceRoute:(id)sender{
 //trace route between user location and annotation selected
}
```

is defined in order to trace route between user location and annotation mapkit. In IB, defined a button and linked to that action, it works. But I do not understand  how I can enable a button not defined programactically but in the interface builder. Any help is apreciated!

Comment: first iboutlate the button and where u have to do enable and disable dowith this line   self.Btnname.userInteractionEnabled=NO; & self.Btnname.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
-(void)traceRoute:(id)sender{
     UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
     [button setEnable:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IN the IB we do have option of enabled. And if we want to enable/disable it according to the conditions, then we need to create the outlet of button and handle it programmatically.

Comment: My question  was about that. And, in IB it is possible to enable the button but is not object of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define that button in the view controller interface:

```
IBOutlet UIButton* myButton;
```

Connect this outlet to your button in the IB, then you can do:

```
[myButton setEnabled:YES];
```